# using row filter to get specific names from table

Tags: filter, row

There is a code for filtering fields from a query (fname, lname and location) into a DataGridView:

```
Dim DV As New DataView(dbdataset1)
DV.RowFilter = String.Format("fname like '%" & Me.tbSearch.Text.Trim & "%'")
DataGridView.DataSource = dbdataset1
```

The filter can find `lname`, `location` but not `fname`:

[image]

here is the screen shot of the populated fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the DataGridView element I can tell you're on ASP.NET 2.0 or below. Anyway, I got it working on ASP.NET 4.7 like this:

ASPX file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind (VB.Net):

```
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Dim dbdataset1 As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow

        dbdataset1.Columns.Add("fname")

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            dr = dbdataset1.NewRow()

            dr("fname") = "picture" + i.ToString()
            dbdataset1.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            dr = dbdataset1.NewRow()

            dr("fname") = "document" + i.ToString()
            dbdataset1.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next

        Dim DV As New DataView(dbdataset1)

        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("fname like '%" & Me.tbSearch.Text.Trim & "%'")

        Me.GridView1.DataSource = DV
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just replace my `GridView1` with your `DataGrdiView`.

[image]
[image]

UPDATE:

So the filter was fixed by the user deleting and adding the Texbox control again into the form.

Comment: hey thanks for your response , the last line in your code .databind () was this a control assigned in the datagrid view?

Comment: `Binds the data to the GridView control.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx Your DataGridView must have a DataBind too.

Comment: It binds `DV` to `GridView` control, otherwise data won't be displayed.

Comment: ok im trying to filter the information from the first and last names column in my mysql database but each time i run the DV.RowFilter = String.Format("[fname] like '%{0}%',textbox2_firstname) it says column fname not found

Comment: the command works with my combo box and the lastname textbox but not with the firstname

Comment: It's not finding the column in the dataset returned from the query/table. Maybe it has another name distinct than "fname". Does `DV` has records? You can try displaying all of them on another DataGridView and it will show you also the correct column name: `Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
Me.DataGridView1.DataBind()`

Comment: You gotta be sure your query is returning a column named `fname`.

Comment: yes the dv has records that i query from my database , im using two data grid views on seperate tabs the first grid view works just fine with the code so all i did was adopt into the next tab

Comment: i checked my database column  name and the name is correct

Comment: I need to know how are those DataGridViews are being loaded (On_PageLoad, OnClick event). Remember that after a Postback some data might be lost, so you must ensure that the data is still there (in `DV`) when you're applying your filter. The error's very clear, the column's not being found because of a missing data or reference. Or maybe you're just giving it another name in your query: `SELECT fname as name FROM User`

Comment: the data grid is handled in a on page load since i want data to be loaded on page start up

Comment: I suggest you to edit your original post and provide the entire code in order to know the details. Or you could replicate this issue on another webform and post it as well.

Comment: Private Sub Queriesmenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
        "Server=mobile;userid=admin;password=admin;database="
        Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim bsource As New BindingSource

Comment: On the main post, and try to give it format as I did on the above answer, please. It's important to know what's happening on the code behind to determine the error's cause.

Comment: please check on my editing post of the code above maybe that will give you more insight